# How to access the web with Python?

Tags: python

I want to access websites without using their API. Would i do this by using something like Mechanize?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two suggested answers:

http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html

Good introduction is also a chapter from Dive into Python3 [Chapter 13. HTTP Web Services](https://diveintopython3.net/http-web-services.html)

Comment: Ofcourse i've used Google, but i thought there were frameworks that would do all of the mundane tasks by itself. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Why I hate the anwer "ask google": the answers I find on SO after asking google always want me to ask google.

Comment: @dwich, the "Chapter 11..." link in your answer is no longer available.

Answer (score 8):

You can access websites by HTTP protocol client: [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html)

Though maybe you'd like [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html), in specific the urllib2.urlopen

Here's little example about using urllib2:

```
import urllib2
page = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/").read()
print page
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#for Python 3.2
import urllib.request
page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.google.com")
print (page.read())
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [urllib.request](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) in python 3.x, and urllib2 in python 2.x